# Why do win32 paths in msys2 bash not resolve links during traversal?

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, symlink, msys2

I have files on a windows machine with hard links (directory junctions) in the following
layout:

```
A/
|-B/ <=> N/
|-C

M/
|-N/
|-O/
```

Now running bash in msys2, I run the following commands (with output following each)

```sh
$ ls 'A/B/..'
N  O
```

```sh
$ ls 'A\B\..'
B  C
```

Using the win32 path, it does not traverse the link. Why is the output of these two commands different?

I also tried using absolute unix and win32 paths, which did not deviate; any win32 path (uses backslashes or rooted by a drive letter) doesn't follow the link while traversing the path.

EDIT: `ls` in powershell returns the same as the win32 path, so maybe the issue is with how windows resolves paths?

Comment: There is something that converts the path to unix style before giving it to the `ls`. Maybe the said thing tries to eliminate `..` as a part of the conversion, without looking at the file system? See [MSYS2 - Filesystem Paths](https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/). Consider reporting it as a bug.

Comment: I considered that, but as you can see in my edit, the same behavior is exhibited in powershell, and even using the `fs.readlink` function in a windows distribution of Node.js

Comment: I must have mixed something I tried up, because node.js's readlink (both msys2 node and native windows node) actually throws an unknown error reading such a path, but python gives me a specific error: `OSError: [WinError 4390] The file or directory is not a reparse point: 'node_modules\\@bentley\\imodeljs-backend\\..'`

Comment: And a reparse point error means it's just not a symlink and therefore readlink doesn't apply and errors out. I care about the link in the path afterall, not any link at the end

Comment: What do you see when you use dir in a command window?

Comment: the same list as `ls` (`A  B`), the path is lexically followed in all windows commands I've tried